# selecting database while connecting mongodb

Tags: linux, mongodb, shell

I want to send a command to mongodb from a shell script. Before Mongodb 2.6 I could do this with the following command:

```
mongo --host db.example.com/mydb -u myuser -pMyPassword --eval 'db.getSiblingDB("mydb").addUser("someone","passss")';
```

or I could run a javascript file providing it like:

```
mongo --host db.example.com/mydb -u myuser -pMyPassword  some.js;
```

After upgrading to 2.6 version of Mongodb, these commands no longer work for me.

Is there any way to select a database and run a command on it? Remember that I want to run a command from a linux shell script.

Or is there a better way to add a mongodb user and run a javascript file from a shellscript?

Comment: Did you try `mongo --help` and `mongo --version` ?

Comment: yes I tried and used '--authenticationDatabase' argument for the first command. but this does not work for the second command.

Comment: "does not work for me" is not very descriptive of your problem. What does is say/complain? And what about --verbose?

Comment: it does not give an error, just not select the database given as argument. it selects test database automatically.

Comment: Did you try
mongo mydbname --eval "my js code" 
?
Check http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#scripting

Answer (score 0):

According to [mongodb help](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/), you can use following line to connect your db in external script.

```
db = connect("localhost:27020/myDatabase");
```

Also you can use following line too

```
mongo localhost:27017/test myjsfile.js
```

See following run for example.

```
$$>mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
$$>mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
connecting to: test
> show dbs
admin  (empty)
local  0.078GB
test   0.078GB
> use stackoverflow
switched to db stackoverflow
> db.questions.insert({a:1})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> show collections
questions
system.indexes
> db.questions.findOne()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547d95c671d7e080cfe5f977"), "a" : 1 }
> exit
bye


$$>mongo test --eval "printjson(db.questions.findOne())"
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
connecting to: test
null

$$>mongo stackoverflow --eval "printjson(db.questions.findOne())"
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
connecting to: stackoverflow
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547d95c671d7e080cfe5f977"), "a" : 1 }
```

Comment: I was using the second one already but after upgrading to 2.6 it does not select the database. The first one, I guess, cannot be used in a linux shellscript.

Comment: @Muatik I think you are doing some kind of basic mistake. I updated my answer, as you can see they work.